# Windows MFC controls get randomly wrong characters

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, mfc

This is an interesting one. I'm in the process of going from satellite DLLs to GNU gettext for translation and encountered this interesting problem. I have tried with hard coded string so gettext isn't the cause of it.

[image: Example of inconsistent encoding]

Here the strings are trated differently in the same menu. "Välj test" and "Stäng test" both contain the same character (ä), but one is displayed correctly while one isn't. When lookin in debugger both strings look fine, but Spy++ confirms that one is wrong. No idea what's going n here.

I'm using MFC in C++ and use Visual Studio 2010 (it's an old project). It's set to Unicode.

Comment: The project migt be Unicode but is the RC file?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense. It should be at least... consistently erroneous! I have noticed that the character in the menu is U+FFFD, which is the character returned if the `MultiByteToWideChar()` function finds a character it cannot convert. Therefore it appears to be an encoding problem. Pls also take into account that the above function is affected by the system's default codepage, if called with `CP_ACP`, maybe test it on a computer with a different codepage. Can you do something "dumb", that is copy and paste the ä from Stäng to Välj, in the same code, resource or app where they are defined?

Comment: Could you [edit] and copy paste the part of the menu containing "Väli test" and "Stäng test" into the question in a properly formatted section?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I found the issue. The GUI is mostly created from the RC file, but some are dynamic. This resulted in some strings being translated twice which mean that the UTF-8 to UTF-16 conversion also ran twice and that corrupted the strings.

Comment: @liftarn you should make this an answer.